# Created a sorted dictionary using LINQ, can't delete entries

Tags: c#, linq

I created a sorted dictionary based of another dictionary using LINQ. Here's the code I used:

```
var sortedStudentRatioDict = from entry in studentRatioDict orderby entry.Value ascending select entry;
```

Now I can't remove any of the entries from that dictionary. The `.Remove()` method isn't showing up in intellisense nor working. How can I remove entries from this dictionary or how can I order a dictionary by value so that I can delete entries? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a dictionary, it's an `IEnumerable`

Comment: That's not a dictionary. Hover over that `var` and visual studio will tell you the type. If you want a sorted dictionary, you could create an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx). I think you'll have to add items to it in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: And if this *was* about dictionaries, sorting a dictionary (if you had one) doesn't magically enable removing its entries. Also, what do you mean by *removing* entries, do you actually mean *filtering* them? Or do you want to delete data from a database? What's the bigger picture?

Answer (score 0):

As [pero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112196/pero) said, it's not a `Dictionary`, it's an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. You can transform it to `Dictionary` by calling `ToDictionary()` method like this:

```
var sortedStudentRatioDict = (from entry in studentRatioDict orderby entry.Value ascending select entry).ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, __ => __.Value);
```

Comment: You *could* do that, but if you did you would have taken an unsorted dictionary, sorted it, and then transformed it back into an unsorted dictionary again. Which would be a bit pointless.

Comment: What would go into those blanks in the .ToDictionary method?

Comment: @JesseWells nothing, it's just names of lambda parameters. You can give 'em any names you want.

Comment: Somewhat; it gave me a better picture of what date type I am dealing with.